# Cordova: unable to find Android SDK folder, but it's correct

Tags: android, cordova, windows-10

When trying to emulate Android for my just created cordova app I got an error:

```
c:\Users\mirko\FirstApp>cordova emulate android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "c:\Users\mirko\FirstApp\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --emulator""
ERROR: Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to 
non-existent path: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Of course, the following 2 lines prove that the folder exists !

```
c:\Users\mirko\FirstApp>cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"

c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk>
```

I already tried to run the command prompt as administrator, but without success.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro as Insider Preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with a full uninstall of Android SDK and reinstalling it per-user and not globally.

After updating PATH variables, all is working well.